# AutoHotKey Invalid Hotkey XButton2 + RButton::

Tags: autohotkey

`XButton2 + RButton::`

`Send, Hello World`

`return`

Apparently this is an invalid hotkey but I don't know why.

Comment: Use `&`. Also please try reading for example [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) documentation page to get started with hotkeys. It'll be better than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

In AutoHotkey, we use the `&` operator when we want multiple keys pressed together to trigger a hotkey. In AHK, the `+` operator instead stands for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

---

Solution:

```
XButton2 & RButton::
Send, Hello World
return
```